# ReferenceError: $ is not defined Version4

Tags: tabulator

I am using version 4 and I am trying to have a button to add a blank row.

When I use the example in the documentation. I get and error message:

ReferenceError: $ is not defined

```js
//Add row on "Add Row" button click
   $("#add-row").click(function(){
   table.addRow({});
   });
```

From what I have read, they all state to add jQuery reference.

How is a button created in version 4, without jQuery.

Thanks

Comment: Could you try and be more specific in your questions/titles at no point do you mention that you are talking about Tabulator, nor do you mention if the click binding is occurring outside of your table definition or inside

Comment: Sorry, I will try to be more specific in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error suggests that you don't have jQuery included in your project any more.

If you have removed it completely from your site when you have transitioned over to version 4.0 of Tabulator then you will need to use the vanilla JS method for adding an event listener:

```
var button = document.getElementById("add-row");

button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    table.addRow({});
});
```

Comment: I tried your script inside the inside the table definition, but I get an error "TypeError: button is null". I then moved the script to the bottom of the page, but still got the same error. Thank you.

Comment: There was an erroneous space before the `.addEventListener` in my original answer, i have updated the answer to resolve it